# write a function to get all elements with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to build my own jQuery function for personal use later, but I'm new in building like these plugins so I started to learn then apply what i want to do, but I faced problems .. 
what I'm trying to build is a jQuery function gets all elements (for now `inputs`) with attribute `data-x` , then apply another jQuery method on it, for example `addClass('class')`
so instead of this complix line of code `$('input[data-x="test"]').addClass('class');` I want to use my function `getElems('x','test').addClass('class');`

this is what I wrote ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pg87ns53/))

```
(function ($){
$.fn.getElems = function( key, value ) {
        var elems = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
            if($(this[x]).data(key) === value) {
                elems.push(this[x]);
            }
        }
        return elems;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

when I try to addClass i got error.. `undefined is not a function`.

Comment: should return jQuery object $(elems); instead of return elems;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plugin should return `this` reference if you want to be able to chain jQuery methods:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.getElems = function (key, value) {
        return this.filter(function() {
            return $(this).data(key) === value;
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

In general you should probably make use of jQuery filter method for this purpose. This way your code will be more jQuery-like.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pg87ns53/3/

Or if you still want to stick with your version with `for` loop, then you will have to return something like `return $(elems);` instead just `elems`:

```
$.fn.getElems = function (key, value) {
    var elems = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
        if ($(this[x]).data(key) === value) {
            elems.push(this[x]);
        }
    }
    return $(elems);
};
```

however this looks a little clumsy.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pg87ns53/4/

Comment: Use `.getAttribute("data-" + key)` instead of `.data(key)`. Less expensive, and doesn't unnecessarily import the data into `jQuery.cache`.

Comment: `.getAttribute("data-" + key)` gets error ... @squint

Comment: @user3003810: "gets error" doesn't tell me much. What's the error? You're probably calling it on the wrong object. It isn't a jQuery method.

Comment: sorry, I forget to write this instead of $(this).. it works fine. @squint

Answer (score 3):

That's probably because you are calling jQuery methods on an array. You could use the `filter` method, and return the filtered collection:

```
$.fn.getElems = function (key, value) {
    return this.filter(function () {
        return $(this).data(key) === value;
    });
}
```

Comment: Be aware data() will convert string number to number, making quite confusing, depending expected result, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/pg87ns53/5/  I'd use instead: `return $(this).data(key) == value;` just in case

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, that's true.

Comment: @A.Wolff Very interesting observation! Indeed can be very confusing.